# How to implement repository design pattern for MongoDB on NestJS

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to figuring out how to implement repository design pattern on NestJS that using MongoDB and mongoose database

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. Do you mean [similar to the model injection shown in the docs?](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#model-injection)

Comment: same thing like repository pattern for typeorm [https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#repository-pattern](typeorm repository pattern) @JayMcDoniel

Comment: That would be basically the same as creating a schema object and using the injection method shown in the [Mongo section of the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#model-injection)

Comment: I’m searching the same, a repository pattern, like spring repository in Java or typeorm, but in the docs only using mongoose directly in the services layer, I dont know if mongoose implement a pattern like active record. Any help?

Comment: I'd like to have a solution like this with a npm package: https://github.com/Thavarajan/Mangoose-Typescript-With-Repository-Pattern

Answer (score 14):

Repository could be injected into the service and it should be included in providers array within the module.

```js
// user.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private readonly userRepository: UserRepository) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.userRepository.findAll();
  }
}
```

```js
// user.repository.ts
@Injectable()
export class UserRepository {
  constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.userModel.find().exec();
  }
}
```

```js
// user.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
  ],
  providers: [UserRepository, UserService],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Comment: What are the advantage of using a repository in service,it look like we are doing the same thing twice and we can do the same thing just by injecting the model in the service

Comment: This is a really simple example, some methods could include some complicated logic. It is better to have a separate data access layer. If changing the database is necessary, only a new repository with an existing interface should be implemented and injected into the service, the service methods will stay the same.

Comment: How can I write unit test for this service?

Comment: @huykon225 this one doesn't make sense to be unit-tested, but usually, repositories and external dependencies are mocked in the services, and some use cases are covered with the tests

Comment: @mirsahib I think it useful for unit test in some case. Example in your's service do query with find().populate()....exec(). In this case, when you test with jest, you must mock find().populate()...exex() that is too complex. But with repository you only mock one function that wrap all query in model mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

I myself asked the exact same question a few months back, and after some research and effort I created `monguito`, a lightweight and type-safe MongoDB Abstract Repository implementation for Node.js.

Furthermore, `monguito` is an open-source Mongoose ODM wrapper and has several cool built-in features, including easy integration in NestJS applications, [polymorphic data model handling support](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/polymorphic-pattern/), and optional audit data support. For further information, please visit [monguito's GitHub site](https://github.com/Josuto/monguito).